# Can't add image via Liquid in Shopify section

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I already read the tutorial, documentary and looked for similar questions. I'm following instructions as I understood them, but I'm missing something here. I'm trying to add the possibility to add an image into a section. I can add an image in the backend, but it won't show.

The position the image with the id badges1 should be loaded:

```
    {%- when 'badges' -%}
            <div class="footer-block__details-content footer-block-badges {{ block.settings.alignment }}">
                  {%- if block.settings.badges1 != blank -%}
                    {{ block.settings.badges1 | img_url: '160x160', scale: 2 | img_tag: block.settings.badges1.alt }}
                  {%- else -%}
                    {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                  {%- endif -%}
              </div>
    {%- endcase -%}
```

The Setting:

```
    {
    "type": "badges",
    "name": "Badges",
    "settings": [
            {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "badges1",
            "label": "Image"
            },
            {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "badges2",
            "label": "Image"
            }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: Is the img tag created into HTML on frontend code, img_tag look not properly formated?

Comment: Silly question, but have you confirmed that your code is reaching the `when 'badges'` block in your switch statement?

Comment: add image in section but your code show in block? Also have you loop blocks outside of that when

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call block in your template code and block is missing in your schema setting.
Use this code in your template code:-

```
 {%- when 'badges' -%}
                    <div class="footer-block__details-content footer-block-badges {{ block.settings.alignment }}">
                          {%- if block.settings.badges1 != blank -%}
                      <img class="if1img" src="{{block.settings.badges1  | img_url: '160x160' }}" alt="{{block.settings.heading1}}" />
                            
                          {%- else -%}
                            {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                          {%- endif -%}
                       {%- if block.settings.badges2 != blank -%}
                              <img class="if1img" src="{{block.settings.badges2  | img_url: '160x160' }}" alt="{{block.settings.heading2}}" />
                          {%- else -%}
                            {{ 'logo' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' }}
                          {%- endif -%}
                      </div>
```